# What's the differences among xx.min.js, xx.debug.js and xx.js?

Tags: javascript

I'm newer to the javascript development. Recently I'm studying the Extjs, but I find that the Extjs has several files, the file names are following:

```
xxxx.min.js
xxxx.debug.js 
xxxx.js
```

So my question is that What are the differences between them, and why? Is there any tools to make these kinds of file, I mean that I create a js file named xxx.js usually, and how can I make xxx.min.js and xxx.debug.js, not copy and change the name manually.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `.min.js` files are 'compressed' in the meaning that there are not line breaks, and there are as few spaces as possible -among another things-. They can be easily created with plugins or online tools, like [JSCompress](http://jscompress.com)
- `.debug.js` files contain debugging instructions, as `console.log` or `console.debug`.
- `.js` files are deployment versions, but still legible and editable (not like the `.min.js` files)